# Painted turtle hit by car!

Tags: health, turtles

My painted turtle escaped his outdoor dry enclosure I walked inside for 5 mins and somehow he was in the middle of a super busy street, he isn't bleeding and the only damage to his shell is some nicks and scrapes on the edge of his right side. What's got me worried is he won't come out of his shell and he won't open his eyes, I'm pretty sure he's swelling.

I have him inside on a heating pad, someone please give me some advice on what to do or what to watch for.
[image]

Comment: How is your turtle?

Answer (score 8):

Get her to a vet. You are asking strangers on the Internet for medical advice here, but you should actually ask a veterinarian. They have the knowledge and equipment to diagnose and hopefully help her.

If **you** got hit by a car, would you ask the Internet to treat you?

Answer (score 4):

Hit by cars, on any animal, need to be seen ASAP. A pet may look fine at first glance but there is a high chance of internal damage that may only be apparent when it's too late.

Your veterinarian will want to do radiographs to check for any broken/displaced bones or ruptured organs.

Depending on the outcome of the exam, pain medicine or anti-inflammatories can be prescribed to allow your turtle to be comfortable during the healing process.

While you get him to a vet keep him warm and in a quiet place, the less stress the better.